# Aside Nietzsche, who are some of other writers of aphorisms?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

After reading Nietzsche, I got hooked on reading books full of aphorisms, especially when they touch a large number of topics. I am wondering if there's any other famous philosophers who like writing aphorisms like Nietzsche.

Comment: Many of the Buddhist and Hindu commentaries are written as aphorisms.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are too many examples to start listing them. A great deal of the 'Wisdom' literature comes in aphoristic form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another writer of aphorisms, who Nietzsche knew and appreciated, was

La Rochefoucauld, Maxims

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/9105/9105-h/9105-h.htm

Answer (score 2):

You might check out out Blaise Pascal’s *Pensées* where you will find this one:

“All of man’s unhappiness comes from his inability to stay peacefully alone in his room.”

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One of my favorite quotes

Answer (score 1):

Aphorisms are a common philosophical tool, one used by any philosopher who approaches points that are metaphysical, mystical, or otherwise difficult to express directly in language. Aphorisms (like koans) are meant to draw the reader beyond the immediacy of language by posing an position that demands active reflection rather than passive acceptance.

There was a trend towards aphoristic writing in the late 19th and early 20th centuries: Nietzsche, Kierkegaard, Husserl, maybe Heidegger, certainly the later Wittgenstein, portions of Sartre, Camus, and other existentialists... That may have been related to the upswing in non-representational art (like cubism, surrealism, da-da, and stream-of-consciousness literature) that occurred around the same time. However, it's worth keeping in mind that a lot of the more aphoristic works of that period were published posthumously from the notes of authors, so the aphoristic style may reflect the incompleteness of the author's own thoughts at the time of his death, rather than any particular stylistic intent.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at Adorno's *Minima Moralia* which has a few sections devoted to very short aphorisms.

Answer (score 0):

Socrates wrote some pretty good aphorisms - some of them can be found in Plato's *Apology*.

Answer (score 0):

You might enjoy reading the works of Emil Cioran(there are plenty of his books translated into English from French and Romanian). 
It covers all the existential problems(and especially religion, where his ideas are very interesting, even though he is usually termed as being a nihilist) of man formulated into striking aphorisms.